# Searchkick - score with multiple fields matching

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, searchkick

The **score** is not increase when I have multiple fields who match.

#### My search method:

```rb
search_results = Subscription.search(
        params[:query], # The search query ("martin" in my example)
        fields: Admin::GlobalSearch.boosts, # An array like ["prénom^3","nom^3.5","email^1.5"]
        operator: "or",
        load: false,
        highlight: true,
        limit: 5,
        misspellings: {below: 5})
```

#### My result for "*martin*" (you have the score at right):

[image: Result for "martin"]

#### My result for "*vincent martin*" (you have the score at right):

[image: Result for "vincent martin"]

Logically, I would like in my second search with "*vincent martin*" the person named **Vincent Martin** have a better score. But he's identical. An idea ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can use the explain option to debug scoring:

```
Subscription.search(params[:query], explain: true, ...).response
```

https://github.com/ankane/searchkick#debugging-queries

Comment: Thanks but it's a bit indigestible... I can see boost and operator **or**. But I don't know how can I do better.

Answer (score 0):

You want to make sure you sort by relevance.

```
search_results = Subscription.search(
        params[:query], # The search query ("martin" in my example)
        fields: Admin::GlobalSearch.boosts, # An array like ["prénom^3","nom^3.5","email^1.5"]
        operator: "or",
        load: false,
        highlight: true,
        limit: 5,
        misspellings: {below: 5},
        order: { _score: :desc }
)
```

Also rather than `explain: true` use `debug: true` it will show you the result set and scores returned. Explain will show you why the scores are the way they are.